# How to fix weight paint issue

Tags: weight-painting

With the weight paint i try to paint. All i have confusion with weight paint. With the brush there are option add subtract etc. In that brush again options mix, add overlay etc.

[image]

[image]

Any simple way to fix the issue. I try weight paint but did not get success any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: use the mix for adding with any weight level, use subtract with 1 level of weight to remove weights, use blur for smoothing the weight contours...

Comment: I see the yellow circle.  Yet I can not be sure what the problem is.  I do not want to guess technical or artistic goals . Try to just describe your goal calmly and why the goal is not met.  I suggest you  place a comparison picture to demonstrate a success example, if one is available .  I do not think your single picture is an adequate explanation.  Maybe others think it is adequate.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger anyway to solve the issue. File is attach in the question. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand much of what you wrote.  I typically do not open a file.